# Installing ArchLinux in VmWare Fusion on M1 Mac

Tags: arch-linux, ext4, nvme

I'm following along in [this](https://infinitescript.com/2022/12/install-arch-linux-arm-on-macbooks-with-apple-m1/) article to install arch in vmware on my m1 mac

I'm able to do `fdisk` just fine, and get the following partition table:

[image: screenshot of fdisk print output]

I then create the filesystem for partition 2 per the article with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p2`.  When I mount this with `mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt`, works fine

But when I attempt to mount the efi filesystem, I get the following:

[image: screnshot of mounting errors]

`dmesg` shows:

[image: screenshot of dmesg output]

Anybody have any thoughts on where to go from here?  Tried specifying `mount -t ext4 ...` but got `VFS: can't find ext4 filesystem`

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a FAT filesystem on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` before you can mount the partition:

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

The step is missing in in the linked tutorial.